# Python - formatting a tuple/string

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my Coursework which I am desperately struggling with I have tried to set my inputs into a dictionary and then use this to format and print the string so that it is displayed as shown below.

> ```
> Surname, Forename   Payroll Department    Salary
> ```
>
> The name should be displayed using the format shown above so you will need to create a string containing the name in this format and print it in a fixed-width field. You may assume that no name will contain more than 30 characters when displayed in this format, no department will contain more than 15 characters, payroll numbers will contain at most 5 digits and all salaries will be integers less than 100,000.

So far I have only managed this as every time I seem to alter any of line 9it comes back with an error saying that "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not strings" but I have no idea how to do this.

```
payroll = int(input("Enter your Payroll.")) 
department = input("Enter your Department Name.") 
salary = int(input("Enter your Salary."))
forename = input("Enter your Forename.")
surname = input("Enter your Surname.")

list_lect = payroll, department, salary, forename, surname

str = '{0[4]},{0[3]}{0[0:5]} {0[2]}    {0[3]}'.format(list_lect)

print(str)
```

Any help would be much appreciated from someone struggling with python.

Comment: It's impossible for a tuple to print like that.

Comment: May I ask WHY you want it printed in this format, aside from the fact that it's not possible to print a tuple in that manner?

Comment: A tuple is a data structure, and has no relationship to how that structure is displayed on a screen. You can of course print  *the data* ***from*** data structures any way you'd like, though.

Comment: It is required for a piece of coursework. It it at all possible to change the tuple into a list again and then formatting it like so ?

Comment: @Shaun are you sure the professor doesn't just want you to print *the data* from the tuple like that? Reproduce the actual assignment text and make it clear it is a homework assignment question. Do this by *editing the question*, not by pasting into comments

Comment: Otherwise we are likely wasting our time based on your (potential mis-)interpretation of the assignment.

Comment: So that homework assignment is nothing like what you wrote.

Comment: So I presume professor taught you about [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) (or assigned you reading about it). Use those techniques and make it look like the above.

Comment: @ArthurDent Thank you for the advice and have looked back on my old notes but am still struggling in finding out how i can include the spaces to make everything look neat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would be simple to make a print function to print the way you want:

```
a = ('Surname', 'Forename', 'Payroll', 'Department', 'Salary')
def printer(tup):
        print_string = str("(")
        pad = 24
        print_string += ", ".join(tup[:2]).ljust(pad)
        print_string += ", ".join(tup[2:4]).ljust(pad)
        print_string += tup[-1] + ")"
        print(print_string)

>>> printer(a)
(Surname, Forename       Payroll, Department     Salary)
```

I would suggest that it would be cleaner to handle this a different way. Perhaps might I recommend taking in the values separately and then combining them in a named way.  Like this

```
payroll = input("Enter your Payroll.") 
department = input("Enter your Department Name.") 
salary = input("Enter your Salary.")
forename = input("Enter your Forename.")
surname = input("Enter your Surname.")
```

You can then perform which ever grouping you want and print them in a more sane manner

```
print("%s, %s      %s, %s     %s" % (surename, forename, .....etc)
```

and then you can store them in a data structure that makes sense as well

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need this? Printing a tuple with spacing is impossible to my knowledge, but I'm sure theres another way to achieve what you're looking for. Aside from that, there is a kind of work around, although you aren't printing a tuple, to say.

```
indexs = {
    payroll = 0,
    dept = 1,
    salary = 2,
    name = 3,
    surname = 4
}
str = "('{surname}', '{name}'      '{payroll}', '{dept}'      
'{salary}')".format(surname = z[indexs[surname]], name = z[indexs[name]], 
payroll = z[indexs[payroll]], dept = z[indexs[dept]], salary = 
z[indexs[salary]])
print(str)
```

Its not perfect, as its just string formatting, but if you want your output to look exactly as you said, this is the only way. Of course your aim might be very different. Anyway, hope this helps